# How can I export swf from Camtasia for Mac?

Tags: export, flash, file-type, camtasia

I am using Camtasia on my Mac and I need to export swf. For now, I am trying to export MP4 and then convert it to swf, but file size gets enormous. Is there a shorter and efficient way to produce swf on Mac?

Answer (score -2):

First you will have to get a .swf converter then you would have to make Camtasia transfer into whatever file the .swf converter can convert.

Comment: I am already doing that as I wrote and this is not an answer, or advise.